# exact matches with regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

Using R, I wrote the following code to identify unique_ids in a dataframe that are not within the following range: gou200-gou250.

Today, someone inputed the id guo201 and the code below did not pick it up. I am not sure why. Any thoughts?

```
 team5_wrong_id=dplyr::filter(team5, !grepl('^(gou)20[1-9]|21[0-9]|22[0-9]|23[0-9]|24[0-9]|25[0]$',unique_id))
```

Comment: You did not group the alternatives

Comment: "gou200" won't match your pattern either, you can simplify to `grepl('gou2([0-4][0-9]|50)', id)` but for your pattern, you need to group like wiktor says `'^(gou)(...)'`

Comment: thank you sooooo much! i grouped and it worked! Serious life saver!